# How does "tying the knot" on this cyclic linked list in Haskell work?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

I am learning Haskell and was reading through [Tying the Knot](http://wiki.haskell.org/Tying_the_Knot#Other_Examples) on how to build a cyclic linked list. In the code

```
data DList a = DLNode (DList a) a (DList a)
mkDList :: [a] -> DList a
mkDList [] = error "must have at least one element"
mkDList xs = let (first,last) = go last xs first
         in  first
         where go :: DList a -> [a] -> DList a -> (DList a, DList a)
               go prev []     next = (next,prev)
               go prev (x:xs) next = let this        = DLNode prev x rest
                                         (rest,last) = go this xs next
                                     in  (this,last)
```

I am trying to understand the call where they link the last element to the first through a "little trick" (!) called tying the knot:

```
mkDList xs = let (first,last) = go last xs first
```

But I am having difficulty seeing how this works. What is "go" initially called with? And per the comment in the article, how is the first result from "go" "passed back in"?

Thanks!

Comment: Initially `first` and `last` are simply *thunks*, i.e. **unevaluated** expressions, the trick is that the `go` function does not evalute the arguments until their values are ready.

Comment: As an experiment, I tried to adapt the knot-tying code to Java in an overly literal way, using an explicit `Thunk` class instead of the "implicit thunks" of Haskell: https://gist.github.com/danidiaz/58cbbff4f4d4b6071b3daa2d54409292

Answer (score 2):

Since Haskell is lazy, values are evaluated until strictly necessary. We can walk through a simple example using equational reasoning to see where that gets us.

Start with the simplest example: a one-element list.

```
mkDList [1] == let (first, last) = go last [1] first in first
```

It seems that you can't call `go`, because you don't know what `last` and `first` are equal to yet. However, you can think of them as unevaluated black boxes: it doesn't matter *what* they are, just that you can proceed with equational reasoning with them.

```
-- Just plug last and first into the definition of go
-- last2 is just a renaming of the argument for clarity
go last [1] first == let this = DLNode last 1 rest
                         (rest, last2) = go this [] first
                     in (this, last2)
```

Let's try to evaluate the next call to `go` in the same way.

```
go this [] first == (first, this)
```

Conveniently, we didn't need to imagine any new black boxes; `go` simply evaluates to its original arguments in a slightly repackaged manner.

OK, now we can go back the way we came, and replace the recursive call to `go` with its evaluation.

```
go last [1] first == let this = DLNode last 1 rest
                         (rest, last2) = (first, this)
                     in (this, last2)
```

And we'll plug *this* back into our original equation with `mkDList`:

```
mkDList [1] == let (first, last) = let this = DLNode last 1 rest
                                       (rest, last2) = (first, this)
                                   in (this, last2)
               in first
```

This doesn't look too helpful, but remember, we haven't actually *called* `mkDList` yet; we just used equational reasoning to simplify its definition a little bit. In particular, there are no recursive calls to `go`, just one `let` expression nested in another.

---

Since Haskell is lazy, we don't have to evaluate any of this until it is absolutely necessary, such as when we try to pattern-match against the return value of `mkDlist [1]`:

```
let (DLNode p x n) = mkDList [1] in x
```

To evaluate this expression, we just need to ask the following questions:

1. "What is the value of `x`?" Answer: we need to pattern-match against `mkDList [1]` first.
2. "What is the value of `mkDList`?" Answer: `first`.
3. "What is the value of `first`?" Answer: `this`.
4. "What is the value of `this`?" Answer: `DLNode last 1 rest`

At this point, you have enough information to see that `x == 1`, and `last` and `rest` don't need to be evaluated further. You could, though, pattern match again to see what, for example, `p` is, and discover that

```
p == last == last2 == this == DLNode last 1 rest
```

and

```
n == rest == first == this == DLNode last 1 rest
```

---

The magic is a call like `(first, last) = go last xs first` doesn't actually *need* values for its arguments; it just needs placeholders to keep track of what values `first` and `last` will eventually get when they are evaluated. These placeholders are called "thunks", and they represent pieces of unevaluated code. They let us refer to boxes that we haven't filled with anything yet, and we can pass the empty boxes to `go` safe in the knowledge that somebody will fill them before anyone else tries to look in them. (In fact, `go` itself never does; it simply keeps passing them along until somebody *outside* of `mkDList` tries to look at them.)

Answer (score 1):

We can try some simple input first, to see what's going on there:

```
mkDList [1] = first
    where 
    (first,last) := go last [1] first
                  = let { prev=last; next=first;         -- prev = last
                          x=1; xs=[] }                   -- next = first
                    in go prev (x:xs) next
                       = let this := (DLNode prev 1 rest)  -- a node is constructed, with 
                                      -- the two pointers still pointing into the unknown
                             (rest,last2) := go this [] next
                                           = (next,this) -- rest := next
                                                         -- last2 := this
                         in  (this,last2)                -- first := this
                                                         -- last := last2
```

`let` in Haskell is recursive: same name can appear on both left and right sides of the equation sign, and will refer to the same entity.

First, `go` is called with `last`, `[1]` and `first`. Both `last` and `first` do not yet refer to any value; they exist only as identity, kind of "named pointers" to still empty boxes, boxes which are yet to be "filled" with values.

Going into the guts of `go`, both names are "fleshed out", and then the final *value* `(this, last2)` is returned; then the pattern `(first, last)` is matched with that value. This is how the `last` finally gets its value, even though it was used as a named identity inside the `go` invocations. This is what is referred to as the tying of the knot: imagine an arrow going "out" of `last` into the `go` invocations, coming back to it from the deep; and same with `first`; thus creating chains of equivalences:

```
    first := this = (DLNode prev 1 rest)
    last := last2 := this
    prev = last
    rest := next = first
```

The above follows a somewhat imperative view of Haskell's semantics as a single-assignment language. The `:=` operator is used, as a pseudocode, to provide a visual clue to the fact that a value is calculated by the expression on the right, and is "passed" into the variables in the pattern on the left of the equality sign (when that pattern is matched with the calculated value).

---

In fact, the name "next" is no good, as we're just passing along the very *first* node all the way down, to be used as the last node's *next node*:

```
 mkDList xs@(_:_) = first where (first,last) = go last xs first

 go ::   DList a ->  [a]  ->        DList a -> (DList a, DList a)
 go          prev  (x:xs)            first = 
    (this,                     last)        -- (this   , last   )
     where 
     this                                 := DLNode 
             prev   x    rest
     (                   rest, last)      := go 
             this     xs             first 

 go          prev     []             first = 
                                    (first,  -- first --> rest of the last node
             prev)
```

This can be "described" by equivalent Prolog definition:

```erlang
mkDList(    [X|XS], First) :-                 % mkDList( in, out)
  go( Last, [X|XS], First,   First, Last).    % go( in, in, in, out, out)

go(   Prev, [X|XS], First,   This,  Last) :-   This = dlnode(Prev, X, Rest),
  go(  This,   XS,  First,   Rest,  Last).    % fill the Rest, return Last
go(   Prev, [],     First,   First, Prev).
```

Indeed,

```erlang
?- mkDList([1,2,3],X).
X = dlnode(_S1, 1, _S2), % where
    _S2 = dlnode(X, 2, _S1),
    _S1 = dlnode(_S2, 3, X).
```